# Fgets get ignored & program only read 2 input data (linked list)

Tags: c, struct, fgets

1. My first fgets get ignored when i run it, it straight jump to the second fgets why it is?i expect it will the fgets to get the user input for student name but it doesn't.So i cannot get the name for student

   ```
   printf("Enter the name of the student\n");
               fgets(name, 100, stdin);
   printf("Enter the gender of the student\n");
               fgets(gender,100,stdin);
   printf("Enter the course of the student\n");
               fgets(course,100,stdin);
               number++;
   ```
2. My print_begin() function could print out 2 input data which mean if the studentlist have 4 struct it only print out two. But my print_last work well to print all the input.

   ```
   void print_begin(){

   struct node *tempdisplay;
   tempdisplay = studentlist;

   if (studentlist == NULL)
   printf("List is empty\n");
   else
   {
       while (tempdisplay!= NULL)
       {
       printf("student name   = %s", tempdisplay->student_name);
       printf("student gender = %s", tempdisplay->student_gender);
       printf("student course = %s", tempdisplay->student_course);
       printf("Student Number = %d\n\n", tempdisplay->student_number);
       tempdisplay = tempdisplay->next;
       }
   }
   printf("\n\nPress any key to go back main menu\n");
   getch();
   }
   ```

this is the whole code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node
{
    char student_name[40];
    char student_gender[40];
    char student_course[40];
    int student_number;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}*newnode, *studentlist,*temp,student;

void insert_last(){

}

void print_begin(){

    struct node *tempdisplay;
    tempdisplay = studentlist;

    if (studentlist == NULL)
        printf("List is empty\n");
    else
    {
        while (tempdisplay!= NULL)
        {
            printf("student name   = %s", tempdisplay->student_name);
            printf("student gender = %s", tempdisplay->student_gender);
            printf("student course = %s", tempdisplay->student_course);
            printf("Student Number = %d\n\n", tempdisplay->student_number);
            tempdisplay = tempdisplay->next;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nPress any key to go back main menu\n");
    getch();
}

void print_last(){
    struct node *tempdisplay;
    tempdisplay = studentlist;

    if (studentlist == NULL)
        printf("List is empty\n");
    else
    {
        while (tempdisplay->next != NULL)
        {
            tempdisplay = tempdisplay->next;
        }
        while (tempdisplay != NULL)
        {
            printf("student name   = %s", tempdisplay->student_name);
            printf("student gender = %s", tempdisplay->student_gender);
            printf("student course = %s", tempdisplay->student_course);
            printf("Student Number = %d\n\n", tempdisplay->student_number);
            tempdisplay = tempdisplay->prev;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nPress any key to go back main menu\n");
    getch();
}

void remove_student(){

}

void insert_new(char name[], char xgender[], char xcourse[], int number){
    newnode = NULL;
    newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    strcpy(newnode->student_name,name);
    strcpy(newnode->student_gender, xgender);
    strcpy(newnode->student_course, xcourse);
    newnode->student_number = number;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->prev = NULL;

    if (studentlist == NULL)
    {
        studentlist = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        while (studentlist->next != NULL)
        {
            studentlist = studentlist->next;
        }
        newnode->prev = studentlist;
        studentlist->next = newnode;
    }

    printf("Insert success\n");
    printf("Press any key to go back main menu\n");
    getch();
}

main()
{
    studentlist=NULL;
    char name[40];
    char gender[40];
    char course[40];
    int number = 0;
    int main_choice;

    do{
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("               1.Add a new student to the beginning\n");
        printf("               2.Add a new student to the end\n");
        printf("               3.Print out the entire list from the beginning\n");
        printf("               4.Print out the entire list from the end\n");
        printf("               5.Remove a student from the list\n");
        printf("               6.Quit the program\n");
        printf("\n\nEnter the number of the options\n");
        scanf("%d", &main_choice);
        switch (main_choice){
        case 1: {
                    printf("Enter the name of the student\n");
                    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
                    printf("Enter the gender of the student\n");
                    fgets(gender,100,stdin);
                    printf("Enter the course of the student\n");
                    fgets(course,100,stdin);
                    number++;

                    insert_new(name,gender,course,number);
        }break;
        case 2: insert_last(); break;
        case 3: print_begin(); break;
        case 4: print_last(); break;
        case 5: remove_student(); break;
        case 6:{
                   printf("\n\n\nThe program is closing...\n...\n");
                   return 0;
                }break;
        }
        system("cls");
    } while (main_choice != 6);
}
```

Comment: tldr ... you are probably mixing `scanf()` and `fgets()`. The `scanf()` leaves the `'\n'` in the input buffer and `fgets()` reads an empty line.

Comment: Also dont put `return 0` inside `case 6`. It will come out of loop anyways in that case

Comment: It might be worth it if you took a second to read your code and evaluate if this is the shortest possible program that exhibits the problem. You might want to read this: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @pmg How should i edit it? i just replace the fgets to all the scanf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons for your problems are

1. Same reason as `@pmg` mentioned in comments. `fgets` reads an empty line left over due to `scanf`. To solve this, use `fgets` to read the `mainchoice` to temporary `char` buffer. Use `atoi` to convet it to `int` and store in `x`. Rest of the program will be same. Try to [avoid scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).
2. In `insert_new`, you are changing the `studentlist` pointer. So this causes problem while printing from start. Use a temporary variable to reach till the end. Dont alter `studentlist`. It should always point to start of the list. Do in the same way as you did in `print` function.

Comment: for the second problem, i edit already but still the same.I entered 4 student data to the end. But when i print out the entire list from the beginning , it only shows the third and fourth student data and ignore the first and thee second. But it work well if i print from the last.